combining rows in a column of the same range in R
I have datafile with start and end values and another column with 0 and 1.
0: the end value of one row is not coinciding with the start value of the next
1: if the end value from one row coincides with the start value of the next row



chr
start
end
value




1
1000
5000
0


1
5500
5800
1


1
5700
6300
1


1
6500
7000
0


1
7200
8000
0


1
7500
9000
1


1






I would like to merge the rows according to how the start and end are coinciding.



chr
start
end




1
1000
5000


1
5500
6300


1
6500
7000


1
7200
9000



I am struggling to figure out a strategy to merge these columns.

The ivs package (interval vectors) has a lot of functionality for finding, locating, grouping all kinds of interval types (e.g. contains, start, end, within):
library(ivs)
library(dplyr)

df |>
  reframe(r = iv_groups(iv(start, end)), start = iv_start(r), end = iv_end(r), .by = chr) 
#   chr            r start  end
# 1   1 [1000, 5000)  1000 5000
# 2   1 [5500, 6300)  5500 6300
# 3   1 [6500, 7000)  6500 7000
# 4   1 [7200, 9000)  7200 9000


I am not sure I completely understand what the rules are but this gives the same result as the expected data frame shown in the question. (Inputs are defined reproducibly in the Note at the end.)
library(dplyr)

DF2 <- DF %>%
  mutate(run = cumsum(lead(value, default = 0) == 1 | value == 0)) %>%
  summarize(start = min(start), end = max(end), value = first(value), 
    .by = c(chr, run)) %>%
  select(-run)

identical(DF2, target)
## [1] TRUE

Note
DF <- data.frame(
  chr = rep(1L, 6L),
  start = c(1000L, 5500L, 5700L, 6500L, 7200L, 7500L),
  end = c(5000L, 5800L, 6300L, 7000L, 8000L, 9000L),
  value = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)
)
target <- data.frame(
  chr = rep(1L, 4L),
  start = c(1000L, 5500L, 6500L, 7200L),
  end = c(5000L, 6300L, 7000L, 9000L),
  value = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)
)

